# Draw 3D Rectangle/Polygon with Elevation and Lowering Effect in PyQt

Tags: python, 3d, pyqt

In Java, you can draw 3-d rectangles using (see https://way2java.com/awt-graphics/4891/):

```
void fill3DRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean raised)
```

Here, the last parameter "raised" is used to lower/elevate the 3d rectangle with respect to the drawing surface.

How can I achieve this effect in PyQt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no built in PyQt 3D paint widget/function as you can only paint 2D polygons. But we can create a custom class to emulate 3D painting. From your Java linked [reference](https://way2java.com/awt-graphics/4891/):

> Java supports 3D rectangles  but the effect of third dimension is not very visible. As the elevation is less, the effect is negligible. **Java designers gave the effect of 3D by drawing lighter and darker lines along the rectangle border.**

We can *emulate* the effect of Java's 3D paint function:

```
void fill3DRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean raised)
```

> This method draws a solid 3D rectangle with the above specified parameters. The last boolean parameter *true* indicates elevation above the drawing surface and *false* indicates etching into the surface.

To obtain a 3D effect in Python we can essentially do the same thing by having two shades of a color then darkening and lighting some sides.

[image: Example pic]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Rectangle3D(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # Elevated 3D rectangle color settings
        self.elevated_border_color = QtGui.QColor(111,211,111)
        self.elevated_fill_color = QtGui.QColor(0,255,0)
        self.elevated_pen_width = 2.5

        # Lowered 3D rectangle color settings
        self.lowered_border_color = QtGui.QColor(0,235,0)
        self.lowered_fill_color = QtGui.QColor(0,178,0)
        self.lowered_pen_width = 2.5

    def draw3DRectangle(self, x, y, w, h, raised=True):
        # Specify the border/fill colors depending on raised or lowered
        if raised:
            # Line color (border)
            self.pen = QtGui.QPen(self.elevated_border_color, self.elevated_pen_width)
            # Fill color
            self.fill = QtGui.QBrush(self.elevated_fill_color)
        else:
            # Line color (border)
            self.pen = QtGui.QPen(self.lowered_border_color, self.lowered_pen_width)
            # Fill color
            self.fill = QtGui.QBrush(self.lowered_fill_color)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)

        # Draw border color of rectangle
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.setBrush(self.fill)  
        painter.drawRect(x, y, w, h)

        # Cover up the top and left sides with filled color using lines
        if raised:
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.elevated_fill_color, self.elevated_pen_width))
        else:
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.lowered_fill_color, self.lowered_pen_width))

        painter.drawLine(x, y, x + w, y) 
        painter.drawLine(x, y, x, y + h)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.draw3DRectangle(50,50,300,150,True)
        self.draw3DRectangle(50,250,300,150,False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 

    widget = Rectangle3D()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what level of paint you want to use:

There are 2 options:

- Using QPainter:

This effect can be achieved by drawing 2 displaced rectangles where the color of the background rectangle is darker than the color of the front:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


def draw3DRect(painter, rect, color, raised=False, offset=QtCore.QPoint(4, 4)):
    if raised:
        painter.fillRect(rect.translated(offset), color.darker())
    painter.fillRect(rect, color)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        r = QtCore.QRect(
            self.width() / 4,
            self.height() / 4,
            self.width() / 2,
            self.height() / 2,
        )
        draw3DRect(painter, r, QtGui.QColor("green"), raised=True)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(320, 240)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

- Using QGraphicsDropShadowEffect:

In this case the QWidget and QGraphicsItem support this effect:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
    rect_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 200, 100))
    rect_item.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("green"))
    effect_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(
        offset=QtCore.QPointF(3, 3), blurRadius=5
    )
    rect_item.setGraphicsEffect(effect_item)
    scene.addItem(rect_item)

    rect_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    rect_widget.setFixedSize(320, 240)
    rect_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:green;")
    effect_widget = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(
        offset=QtCore.QPointF(3, 3), blurRadius=5
    )
    rect_widget.setGraphicsEffect(effect_widget)

    lay.addWidget(view)
    lay.addWidget(rect_widget)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]